# Flexslider fixed image

Tags: css, flexslider

I am using flexlider within shopify.  I would like the images within the slider to have a fixed size with css but always spread 100% in width without looking squashed in height.  So if I'm uploading an image thats 597px height, I would need it to display in 450px but the aspect ratio to remain the same.  Is there a way to do this with flexslider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `flexslider.css` you have an style rule:

```
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
```

Which you may replace with something like this:

```
.flexslider .slides img {width: auto; height: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Please let me know if that helped you.